# Trying to integrate Python with Docker. Getting error on input portion of code

Tags: python, docker

I have a very simple python script. I am trying to use it in a docker container.

Python file (computer.py)

```
import datetime
print("Welcome to virtual assistant.")
name = input("What is your name? ")
print("Welcome " + name)
def time():
print(datetime.datetime.now())
command = input("Would you like to know the time " + name + "?")
if command == "yes":
print(time())
```

And My docker file looks like this.(Docker)

```
FROM python:3

ADD computer.py /

CMD [ "python", "./computer.py" ]
```

Then I ran

```
docker build -t python-barcode .
```

Then

```
run python-barcode
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./computer.py", line 4, in <module>
    name = input("What is your name? ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
Welcome to virtual assistant.
What is your name? %
```

It seems to run the code up untill I ask for input? Not even sure what would cause that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a container with `docker run`, *stdin* is by default not connected, so anything that attempts to read interactive input will fail.  You probably want to run:

```
docker run -it python-barcode
```

The `-i` leaves *stdin* connected, and the `-t` allocates a tty which is what you normally want to interactive input.

Comment: Thank you that worked! Are the -i and -t just docker arguments? just so I can look up a comprehensive list.

Comment: That's correct; you can find those documented in the [docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/).

Answer (score 0):

you shold run the container in interactive mode with the -i and -t

`docker run -it python-barcode`